# Why does this Tensorflow program work?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm running on Mac OS 10.12.4, Anaconda Python 3.5 and Tensorflow 1.1.
I have cobbled together the reproducible code shown below. 
I have defined "my_model" with arguments "features" and "labels".
I did not define them. The "my_model" function is called without any arguments.
My Spyder "variables" window does not show them after the program runs.
My question is: where are these variables defined?

Charles

```
from sklearn import metrics, cross_validation
from tensorflow.contrib import layers
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

# shut up the warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

def my_model(features, labels):
    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 3, 1, 0)
    features = layers.stack(features, layers.fully_connected, [10, 20, 10])
    prediction, loss = (learn.models.logistic_regression(features, labels))
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss,
        tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        optimizer='Adagrad',
        learning_rate=0.1)

    return {'class': tf.argmax(prediction, 1), 'prob': prediction}, loss, train_op

df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
df = df.sample(frac=1)  # shuffle all rows
print(df.head())
column_names = list(df.columns[:4])
X = df[column_names].as_matrix()
y = df['Species']
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df["Species"])
y = le.transform(df["Species"])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
  X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=35)

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn = my_model)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, steps=1000)

y_predicted = [p['class'] for p in classifier.predict(x_test, as_iterable=True)]
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted)
print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(score))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_model` is not called in your code. It is a callback function called by `Estimator` with 2 arguments: features and labels.

They are actually `x_train` and `y_train` for the fit() function.

---

As [the doc](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/tf.contrib.learn.Estimator.md) says, *"Model function, takes features and targets tensors or dicts of tensors and returns predictions and loss tensors. E.g. "(features, targets) -> (predictions, loss)"*

And you can see model_fn is called in line 1125 in the [source code of Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py):

```
model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
```